# Html 5 (section)

Tags: html, html5

в чем прикол использования тега <section> чем он лучше простого <div>??

Answer (score 1):

Семантическая разметка страницы.

Может пригодиться в будущем для поисковой оптимизации, для всякого рода экранных ридеров, ну и собственно для самого верстальщика или разработчика, разметка странницы становиться более читаемой.